# How do I update an object within a list based on an object's key (and not the whole object)?

Tags: php, json, mongodb, symfony, php-mongodb

### Question:

How do I update an object within a list based on the specific key within that object?

### Description:

Say I have the following object in my mongodb:

```
{
    "keysteps":[
        {"timecode":"01:00:00", "title": "Chapter 1"}
    ]
}
```

And say I would like to update "keysteps" with a list of keysteps (aka: "chapters"), how would I go about making sure that if a timecode already exists, that I update the object instead of creating a new one?

If I update my mongodb with these keysteps:

```
{
    "keysteps":[
        {"timecode":"01:00:00", "title": "Chapter 1 - edited"}
    ]
}
```

Here is the output I get:

```
keysteps": [
      {
        "timecode": "01:00:00",
        "title": "Chapter 1"
      },
      {
        "timecode": "01:00:00",
        "title": "Chapter 1 - edited"
      }
    ]
```

Instead of updating keysteps, it added a new object within the keysteps list. **If I had sent the same timecode object (same timecode and title) it would not have created a new one.**

### What I've done:

This is a snippet from my Symfony controller that I use to update:

```
class VideoToolsController extends Controller
{
    //More code

    public function keystepsUpdateAction(Request $request, int $video_id){
        //If the video id already exists, throw an error

        $keystepsS = $this->get('video_tools.keysteps');
        $exists = $keystepsS->exists($video_id);

        //Return immediately if keysteps doesn't exist.
        if(!$exists)
            return JsonResponseService::getErrorBadRequest("Keystep does not exist.");

        $keysteps = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        //die(var_dump($data));
        $form = $this->createForm(KeystepsType::class);
        $form->submit($keysteps);
        //return new JsonResponse($data);
        //Return bad request if the form is not valid.
        if(!$form->isValid())
            return JsonResponseService::getErrorBadRequest("Keysteps are not valid, try again.");

        try {
            $res = $keystepsS->update($video_id, $keysteps['keysteps']);
            return JsonResponseService::getSuccess($res, "Updated keysteps.");

        } catch(Exception $exception){
            return JsonResponseService::getErrorBadRequest($exception->getMessage(), $keysteps);
        }
    }
    //More code
}
```

This is a snippet from my Php service that I use to update:

```
class KeystepsService {

    //More code

    //TODO: Make timecode UNIQUE
    public function update($video_id, $keysteps) : int {

        $updatedOne = $this->mongoCollection->updateOne(
            ['video_id' => $video_id ],
            ['$addToSet' => [ "keysteps" => [ '$each' => $keysteps ]]]
        );

        return $updatedOne->getModifiedCount();
    }

    //More code
}
```

### mongodb/mongo-php-library:

[mongodb/mongo-php-library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library)

*Feel free to give me advice on how to word the title/question, I feel as if it's not on point.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered, the `$addToSet` operator is not the right thing to use here. This is by design since the "set" is of the "objects" in the array, and if you give a different combination of values in the keys in any way then this is a "new" object and is added.

So the correct way to handle this is with "two" operations:

1. Attempt to find the item where it **does exist** in the array by key and then update it with [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)
2. Attempt to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) the item to the array if the key **does not exist**.

Clearly you don't want to be writing and waiting for a response from the database for multiple operations, so instead you use the [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-bulkWrite/) method to send both at once:

```
$this->mongoCollection->bulkWrite([
  [ 'updateOne' => [ 
    [ 'video_id' => $video_id, 'keysteps.timecode' => $keysteps[0]['timecode'] ],
    [ '$set' => [ 'keysteps.$.title' => $keysteps[0]['title'] ] ]
  ]],
  [ 'updateOne' => [
    [ 'video_id' => $video_id, 'keysteps.timecode' => [ '$ne' => $keysteps[0]['timecode'] ] ],
    [ '$push' => [ 'keysteps' => $keysteps[0] ]
  ]]
])
```

Note that whilst still keeping your array object structure but deliberately not using `$each` here due to the nature of this two step operation. If your input can have more than one array item in it, then you would loop the items and create the "pair" of operations pulling the array values out by index.

So the `0` index usage here is just a placeholder for the index variable you would use to drive this in supporting multiple array items within input. You also would just generate the "internal" documents for the "operations" rather than actually issue the [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-bulkWrite/) several times. The whole point of this method is after all to call it only once.

**Edit working solution:**

```
public function update($video_id, $keysteps) : int {

    $modifiedData = 0;
    foreach($keysteps as $keystep){
        $bulkUpdate =  $this->mongoCollection->bulkWrite([
            [ 'updateOne' => [
                [ 'video_id' => $video_id, 'keysteps.timecode' => $keystep['timecode'] ],
                [ '$set' => [ 'keysteps.$.title' => $keystep['title'] ] ]
            ]],
            [ 'updateOne' => [
                [ 'video_id' => $video_id, 'keysteps.timecode' => [ '$ne' => $keystep['timecode'] ] ],
                [ '$push' => [ 'keysteps' => $keystep ]
                ]]
            ]]);
        $modifiedData += $bulkUpdate->getModifiedCount();
    }

    return $modifiedData;
}
```

Comment: @rottenoats I Hope the syntax is okay, my PHP is a bit rusty, But I hope at least the general intent comes through

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to Neil's answer, it may worth to just pull the duplicates first, then push new chapters:

```
public function update($video_id, $keysteps) : int {
    $timecodes = array_map(function($chapter){return $chapter['timecode'];}, $keysteps);

    $updatedOne = $this->mongoCollection->updateOne(
        ['video_id' => $video_id ],
        ['$pull' => [ 'keysteps' => [ 'timecode' => ['$in' => $timecodes]]]]
    );

    $updatedOne = $this->mongoCollection->updateOne(
        ['video_id' => $video_id ],
        ['$addToSet' => [ 'keysteps' => [ '$each' => $keysteps]]]
    );

    return $updatedOne->getModifiedCount();
}
```

My rationale is it should work with arbitrary sub-documents with a key field 'timecode', so for example wish you add a 'description' field to subdocuments instead of changing the title, it still works.

Wrapping it with bulk writes is a good idea, but is not essential. It is not a replacement of transaction, so if it is critical to take care of concurrent updates, something like an optimistic lock should be used.